# Create object in correct scope

Tags: java, object, scope

Because I create the object in a method inside the A-class, it is out of scope when I need to use the methods of the object in another method(inside A). The reason behind why I want to create the objects in a method is because the number of objects created depends on the user input.

Is there some way to be able to use the objects outside the method?

```
public class A {
    //I was thinking I could write something here to change the scope?
    // Like: public B objekt

    public static ArrayList input(){
        input0 = reader.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<input0; i++){
            //user inputs: input1 & and input2
            B object = new B(input1, input2);
            list.add(objekt)
        }

        return list
    }

    public static void doSomething(ArrayList list){
        //Because the objekt is out of scope. I cannot call the method.
        list.get(index).get_input1();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list = A.input()
        A.doSomething(list);
    }
}

public class B {
    public int input1;
    public int input2;

    public B(int input1, int input2){
        this.input1 = input1;
        this.input2 = input2;
     }

     public int get_input1(){
         return input1;
     }
}
```

Comment: Change `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<B>`.

Comment: Just create a static class field and you'll be able to access it from any method.

Comment: Where is `list` defined? We can see where it is used, but you haven't shown where it is defined or constructed. Also, please show code that compiles, or only breaks the compiler for the issue you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your list is defined as:

```
Arraylist List = new ArrayList();
```

The problem you are experiencing is not related to the scope of where you are creating the `B` objects.

Rather, the list contains objects of type `Object`, and therefore you cannot call `get_input1()` on an `Object`.

If you changed the definition of list to:

```
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

... and your method signature to:

```
public static List<B> input() {
```

... then you would be able to call `get_input1()` on the objects in the list.

Of course, you will need to fix the other minor compile issues in your code in order to get it to compile.